# rossrv show not showing the service

Tags: ros, catkin-make, service, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a service "WordCount.srv", it gave no error while compiling but when I try to run command

```
rossrv show WordCount.srv
```

it doesnt show the request and the response of the service neither it gives any error. What might have gone wrong ?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233333/rossrv-show-not-showing-the-service/) by [siddhesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26663/siddhesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [siddhesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26663/siddhesh/) on 2016-04-30**:
Now I sourced it. That was the problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source your workspace after building it?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1